# 2 column layout with text to right of image collapse into 1 column with text above and below?

Tags: css

I have a responsive fluid width website. For one section I have a title, text and an image.

For larger displays I need the title and text to sit to the right of the image. For smaller displays I want a single column with the title first. (see image)

[image]

```
<div class="cont">
  <h1>Here is Title</h1>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>

.cont {
  background: grey;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
}
.img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Is this layout possible? For support reasons I cant use flexbox.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoYMoX

Comment: Use a media query for this

Comment: Even with a media query I dont know how to achieve the layout, or if its even possible (without something like absolute positioning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use your current CSS as default for smaller screens and then use media queries to adjust the layout for larger ones. You may have to use absolute positioning.

For your example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  .img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -200px;
  }
  .cont {
    margin-left: 200px;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

---

**Edit - Alternative Without Absolute Positioning:**

As I mentioned in the comments, you could also place the image in the content twice and then simply hide one as needed with media queries. Not ideal, but at least the browser should only download the image once.

So for example:

```css
.cont-wrap {
  background: grey;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cont {
  float: left;
}
.img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
.left {
  display: none;
  float: left;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  .img {
    display: none;
  }
  .img.left {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-wrap">
  <div class="img left"></div>
  <div class="cont">
    <h1>Here is Title</h1>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really dont want to use absolute positioning. Its not a robust solution for a responsive website with dynamic content.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible without absolute positioning, the image needs to exit the flow of the regular content... an alternative might be to have the image both to the left and within the content, and then just hiding one as needed (the browser should only download it once).

Answer (score 0):

with bootstrap you can use the offset parametrics, and the pull or push orders. 
with the normal css, you can use media query setting position absolute...
     @media all and (max-width:768px){
     .title{position: absolute; 
      top:0; left: 0;

OR 
      width:100%; float:left; ...}
     .bluebox{width:100%; 
      margin-top:20px;}}